# Facebook not giving page link any more

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Has anyone noticed that facebook have stopped giving the page link in the graph api?

Has anyone found a way around this? Please let me know.

Thanks so much

Comment: Bug report here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/216662558444277

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you're right, I don't see the "link" field in the results for pages, even if I try with "PAGE?fields=link" I don't get it.

But it's not that big a problem.. You do get the *id* and *username* fields and so it's very easy to create the page link:

```
"http://www.facebook.com/" + page.id
or
"http://www.facebook.com/" + page.username
```

---

## Edit

I can't really think of scenarios in which the example gave by @GeoffChappell (in the comments) apply in the real world, but there's a solution for that using FQL:

```
SELECT page_url FROM page WHERE page_id = PAGE_ID
```

For [39399781765](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20page_url%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20=%2039399781765) it returns: http://www.facebook.com/RedSox

For [39399781765](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=fql?q=SELECT%20page_url%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20page_id%20=%208936834181) it returns: http://www.facebook.com/pages/jQuery/8936834181

Comment: Those urls will work through the browser because they redirect to the proper url, but they don't work for all cases. E.g. if you want to create a like button for an object, you need to know the 'true' url for the object.

Comment: The "true url" is the *website* field in the page graph object, he asked about the page *link* which according to the documentation is the "Link to the page on Facebook".

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case always. E.g. the true url in the case of https://graph.facebook.com/39399781765 is http://www.facebook.com/RedSox. But for https://graph.facebook.com/8936834181 it's http://www.facebook.com/pages/jQuery/8936834181. Short of following the redirects, I can't see how you can know that since the link attr has been removed.

Comment: You need the true url for deep linking into a page, e.g. to a specific tab on a page. You can't generate that from a permalink because Facebook won't redirect to the proper tab.

Comment: Thanks, the fql solution seems to work even for objects that don't have corresponding fb pages (redirects don't work in those cases).